# How to avoid redirect to Keycloak login on page reload when using openid_client in Flutter web?

Tags: flutter, oauth-2.0, keycloak, openid-client

I've managed to implement the OIDC authorisation PKCE flow on Flutter web using the following tutorial: https://medium.com/@rangika123.kanchana/keycloak-integration-for-flutter-web-using-openid-client-with-authorization-code-flow-489afeac6e9f . Overall everything seems to be working fine. Silent refresh of the token during the same session works just fine. Now I'm struggling with the following problem:

- Whenever I reload the app it will always redirect to keycloak and then it instantly redirects back to app. The instant redirect to web app happens because the user was already authenticated in keycloak, therefore the login form is not displayed.
- Most web apps that I remember using don't redirect to an auth screen/url on page reload. It's all seamless/silent. Is it possible to do the same with openid_client?
- I looked on the web for various answers and I understand that in general it's a good practice to avoid caching refresh tokens in session storage / local storage or cookies to avoid the possibiltiy of XSS attacks.
- Reading this article I learned that there's a technique available to deal with this problem. It's called refresh token rotation. In a nutshell, each server request ends up generating a new refresh token that can be used only once. According to this article such a token is safer to store in local storage (despite not being a secure storage place). Please contradict me if this information is wrong. https://auth0.com/blog/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/
- https://auth0.com/docs/secure/tokens/refresh-tokens/refresh-token-rotation - More about the refresh token rotation technique.
- From other searches I understand that one can init the openid_client with a refresh token and have it ready to make new requests to the resource server (authorised REST api). In theory (if I understand right) a one time use refresh token can be stored in local storage, the app reloads, checks local storage, finds the token, initialises the client and thus it can skip the mandatory redirect to keycloak.
- As far as I understand, keycloak has a setting where one can enable token rotation by enabling "Revoke Refresh Token". Reading more I understand that this setting introduces new issues when multiple tabs are open on the same app. One tab consumes the latest token and then the other tabs enter in an invalid state that requires a new redirect. Again, this is behaviour that I don't see in most apps such as jira, fb, or whatever.
  https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/10937
  https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/14122
  https://github.com/authts/oidc-client-ts/issues/967
- Additional subpoint, for native I've used the native Authenticator since it supports PKCE. I see there the same behaviour, except everything happens much faster since the emulator does not need to download the app. I guess here we don't care that much about the relaod behavior since users don't really do reloads. Maybe opening and starting the app from scratch has the same visual behavior. Then again, I guess I have to use some secure storage solution for the same goal of not getting redirected to keycloak login.

So all in all, my question is, can I avoid the mandatory keycloak redirect safely? Or is storing refresh tokens in local storage (even with token rotation) a bad idea and should be avoided. If so is there any way at all to avoid the redirect? Having the app loaded and intialised twice at each page refresh is rather annoying. Especially during the frequent hot reloads in development. Any advice would be much appreciated. A code sample even more. Cheers!